# Setting relations Grocery CRUD

Tags: codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I have 2 tables

```
Users Table => id , username
OrdersTable => order_id,user_id, qty,total
```

I need to link these two tables with .

> id and user_id.

how can i do this with grocery CRUD.

Comment: nope. Bypassed Grocery_crud altogether for CRUD in orders table

Comment: Presumably you tried the solutions in my answer?

Comment: Not really. Just browsed through it. Thought doing it through custom code would be much easier and got on with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `OrdersTable` as your primary table, you can use a `1:1` relationship using [set_relation()](http://www.grocerycrud.com/crud/example/set_a_relation). This would be if you were viewing an order and wanted to see/set which user the order belongs to.

```
$crud->set_table('OrdersTable');
$crud->set_relation('id','UsersTable','username');
```

This will allow you to select which user for a particular order.

However, presumably a user may have many orders- a `1:n` relationship. This would be the case if UsersTable is your primary table, i.e. you're viewing a `user` in the CRUD and want to see all associated orders.

This method requires an intermediary table, with which you link the two existing tables, and a slight change to your existing table structure. You'd need to remove `user_id` in the `OrdersTable`. The intermediary table, for the sake of argument called `UserOrdersTable` would require the following columns.

```
user_id INT
order_id INT
priority INT
```

You can then add the relationship using the [set_relation_n_n()](http://www.grocerycrud.com/crud/example/set_a_relation_1_n) method.

You can then reverse the `set_relation_n_n()` call for when viewing the `OrdersTable` so you can see which user made an order.

To summarise, a `1:n` relationship using `set_relation_n_n()` will allow you to view orders by a user, and a user for an order.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean query, then;

```
select u.id, u.username, o.order_id, o.qty, o.total
from users u
left join orders o on(o.user_id = u.id)
where 1=1
```